# How to scrape images and titles from Imgur with nokogiri

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, imgur

I'm trying to scrape the images and the titles of https://imgur.com/t/memes with Nokogiri.

This is for a little project, i've already used Nokogiri for **scraping** https://www.reddit.com/r/memes/ before, and it worked great.

```
require 'rest-client'
require 'nokogiri'

page = RestClient.get('https://imgur.com/t/memes')
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(page)
posts = doc.css('.Post-item')
```

The css class that I need it's called '.Post-item', i have also tried with doc.search, and with 'Post-item' instead of '.Post-item', also i've tried with other css classes of that page, and all of them are returning me [], it should be returning a Nokogiri Parse on that class with all of the posts on that page.

Comment: The reason you can't see the items is because imgur serves up, at that URL, a mostly blank page, then uses javascript to load the content. If you do `puts doc.to_html` in your script you can see the HTML page it serves up. You need to come up with a way to get the images and titles by either following one of the JS files/scripts linked in the HTML, or use another tool that will render the page first (headless chrome, for example). You may be better off using the imgur API for this task instead of scraping content

Comment: Ah thanks! It’s as i feared

Answer (score 0):

You will find mostly a blank page when trying to scrape the page at url: https://imgur.com/t/memes because the website renders the data using javascript on the client side.

You will want to use something like the [watir/ruby](https://github.com/watir/watir) gem, that allows you to wait until the webpage and all its scripts have been fully loaded before attempting to parse the webpage, meaning you will find the data you except to when you come to parse the document.